# Pipe Nsis installer log to console druing the silent install

Tags: cmd, console-application, nsis, silent-installer

Is it posible to pipe Nsis installer log to console druing the silent install. Installer is third party so I can't change it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS is a GUI app and does not really support output to the console.

There are two ways to get console output:

- Recompile NSIS with logging to console turned on (NSIS_CONFIG_LOG_STDOUT)
- [Call AllocConsole with the system plugin and print custom output](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?p=2303779#post2303779)

Both of these require changes to the installer so it can only be done by the author of the installer...